# Using a path twice (draw and then decorate)

Tags: tikz-pgf, text-decorations

Is there any way to reuse a path for both drawing and text decorating?

I want to avoid repeating the `(6.8cm,-1.7) -- (9.5cm,-1.7) arc (-90:0:1.5) -- (11cm,1.5)` below.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.text}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->, cyan!50!white, line width=1.5mm ] (6.8cm,-1.7) -- (9.5cm,-1.7) arc (-90:0:1.5) -- (11cm,1.5);
\draw[decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily|gather},text align={center},raise=0.2cm},decorate] (6.8cm,-1.7) -- (9.5cm,-1.7) arc (-90:0:1.5) -- (11cm,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `postaction` is for. You just need to put the argument of the second `\draw[...]` command into `postaction={...}`, and add this to the first path.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.text}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->, cyan!50!white, line width=1.5mm,postaction={decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily|gather},text align={center},raise=0.2cm},decorate}] (6.8cm,-1.7) -- (9.5cm,-1.7) arc (-90:0:1.5) -- (11cm,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use `postaction` arbitrarily often.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.text}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->, cyan!50!white, line width=1.5mm,
postaction={decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily|gather},text
align={center},raise=0.2cm},decorate},
postaction={decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily|hibernate},text
align={center},raise=-0.3cm},decorate},
] (6.8cm,-1.7) -- (9.5cm,-1.7) arc (-90:0:1.5) -- (11cm,1.5);
% sadly, text decorations do not get taken into account automatically
% when determining the bounding box
\path (current bounding box.south) ++ (0,-3mm) 
(current bounding box.east) ++ (3mm,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another way to recycle path is to use the `save path` and `use path` keys. There are attempts to make those more versatile in a future version of Ti*k*Z, so please stay tuned.

Comment: ah, ok -- thanks! Does this extend to multiple actions? (what if I wanted to decorate twice, once on top and the other on the bottom)

Comment: @JasonS Yes, you can use `postaction` twice, or arbitrarily often.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `preaction` or `postaction`

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.text}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->, cyan!50!white, line width=1.5mm,preaction={decoration={text along path, text={|\sffamily|gather},text align={center},raise=0.2cm},decorate} ] (6.8cm,-1.7) -- (9.5cm,-1.7) arc (-90:0:1.5) -- (11cm,1.5);

%\draw[] (6.8cm,-1.7) -- (9.5cm,-1.7) arc (-90:0:1.5) -- (11cm,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `preaction` does not draw things in the same order as in the OP's code.

Comment: Doesn't matter, the result is the same.